# Put a multidimensional numpy array on top of another one using indices

Tags: python, numpy

This problem is pretty much a weird indexing situation.

Assume that we have an array of zeros with this shape (10000, 128, 1) and a second array with non zero values with this shape (40, 128, 1) and a third array defining the indices with this shape (40,).

What i needed and didn't do in a vectorized way is to put the second array inside the first array in the indices specified by the third array.

`np.put(first_array, indices, second_array)`  will not do the job.

The indices may not be continuous and they can be spread.
indices ex. `[9500, 9503, 9555,.... 9999]`

Comment: `first_array[indices] = second_array`? Please include a [mre] with the expected result.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny you are right..